# How can I use anchor among fields?

Tags: entities, blocks

Say we have a page like wikipedia page, with a lot of text fields, finally we need an "outline block" to navigate user to find different fields easily, then we need to use anchor in the page, but I found it is not available to use anchor in different fields. Is there any solution for this? Another question is how to embed the "outline block" in the node content (on top of text)?

Comment: You might try the Drupal TOC module, it sounds like a good fit for this. https://www.drupal.org/project/tableofcontents